# How to convert binary file to jpeg format in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have a file saved in binary format (.bin extension):

```
����JFIF��(ICC_PROFILEmntrRGB XYZ acsp���-  desc�trXYZdgXYZxbXYZ�rTRC�(gTRC�(bTRC�(wtpt�cprt�<mlucenUSXsRGBXYZ o�8��XYZ b����XYZ $����paraff�
Y�
[XYZ ���-mlucenUS Google Inc. 2016��C
```

I was trying something like this (open binary file and save as image), but when trying to open created file, i'm like getting error that file is damaged:

```
    const buffer = Buffer.from(data, 'binary')
    const img = Uint8Array.from(buffer).buffer
    fs.writeFile('id.jpeg', img, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
```

Comment: why are you converting the buffer to a Uint8Array?  Why not write the buffer out directly in `fs.writeFile`?

Comment: you are god, heh thx ;)